# Alterar classe do botão após preencher todos os campos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho um botão que precisa ser habilitado quando o usuário terminar de preencher os campos, porém ele precisa ser alterado a classe quando ficar habilitado...

quando o botão estiver desabilitado eu precisaria que enquanto os campos não forem preenchido o botão fique em satus disabled e com a classe do css cinza, após ser preenchido os campos o botão fica habilitado e com a classe do css verde, isso seria em jQuery? Como faço para funcionar?

```css
.btn-pdf {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.btn-pdf .fa-thumbs-down {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  color: #787878;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.btn-pdf .fa-thumbs-down:hover {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn-pdf .fa-thumbs-up {
  background-color: #59bd59;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.btn-pdf .fa-thumbs-up:hover {
  background-color: #68cb68;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn-pdf a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'KG Blank Space Solid';
  color: #303030;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.btn-pdf a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="msform" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Telefone Válido*</label>
  <input id="celular" type="text" class="form-control" name="celular" placeholder="Telefone">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Selecione uma Opção</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
    <option name= "PMA" value="200">Shopping 1</option>
    <option name = "BRB" value="200">Shopping 2</option>
  </select>
</div>

</form>

<div class="btn-pdf">
   <a href="">
      <i class="far fa-thumbs-down fa-2x"></i><br>Baixar PDF
   </a>
 </div>
 
<div class="btn-pdf">
  <a href="">
      <i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i><br>Baixar PDF
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: aqui tem um ótimo exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/p628Y/1/
sobre o estilo, acredito que seja mais fácil deixar o `css` resolver. Se você aplicar o atributo `disabled` no link, basta usar o seletor `a:disabled` para aplicar o estilo que quiser quando estiver desabilitado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi direito se é para ter 2 botões ou um só e trocar. Bom creio que seja a segunda opção, então fiz um código aqui que deve te mostrar como funciona a verificação de campos.

```js
$(function(){
 // Definimos um evento para os campos, quando alterarem ele deve verificar cada campo.
 $("#msform").find("input,textarea,select").on("change paste keyup",verificarCampos);
  
  function verificarCampos(){
   var falha=false;
    $("#msform").find("input,textarea,select").each(function(){
     // Se o valor for vazio, define que houve falha:
     if($(this).val()=="" || $(this).val()==null) falha=true;
    });
    // Se falhou:
    if(falha) $(".btn-pdf").addClass("cinza");
    else $(".btn-pdf").removeClass("cinza");
  }
  // vou chamar a função assim que o código iniciar, para já definir o botão como inválido:
  verificarCampos();
  
  $(".btn-pdf a").on("click",function(e){
    if($(this).parent().is(".cinza")){
      alert("Informe os dados para continuar");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-pdf {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.btn-pdf .fa-thumbs-down {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  color: #787878;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display:none;
}

.btn-pdf .fa-thumbs-down:hover {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn-pdf .fa-thumbs-up {
  background-color: #59bd59;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.btn-pdf .fa-thumbs-up:hover {
  background-color: #68cb68;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.btn-pdf a {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'KG Blank Space Solid';
  color: #303030;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.btn-pdf a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-pdf.cinza .fa-thumbs-up{
  display:none;
}
.btn-pdf.cinza .fa-thumbs-down{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/js/all.js"></script>
<form id="msform" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Telefone Válido*</label>
  <input id="celular" type="text" class="form-control" name="celular" placeholder="Telefone">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Selecione uma Opção</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="list-lugar" name="unidade">
    <option value="" disabled="true" selected="true">Selecione uma Unidade</option>
    <option name= "PMA" value="200">Shopping 1</option>
    <option name = "BRB" value="200">Shopping 2</option>
  </select>
</div>

</form>

<div class="btn-pdf">
   <a href="http://google.com.br" target="_blank">
      <i class="far fa-thumbs-down fa-2x"></i>
      <i class="far fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i><br>Baixar PDF
   </a>
 </div>
```

Mas atenção: Esse código não verifica se o número digitado é válido. E Também não bloqueia o click no botão caso a classe cinza que você disse estiver no elemento.

Explicando o que fiz:
Usei o jQuery para rodar em todos os campos, procurar por alterações e então verificar se todos os campos foram preenchidos. Depois adicionamos a classe cinza no botão, com a classe cinza o botão esconde o ícone "positivo" e mostra o "negativo". Mais explicações no comentário do código.

Comment: Entendi, eu tentei fazer a validação utilizando blur mas acho que com o seu código consigo modificar para fazer a validação junto, uma dúvida que eu tenho, como faz para deixar ele disable quando for cinza, para a função de download não funcionar

Comment: você pode bloquear o click no javascript mesmo, use algo do tipo:

$(".btn-pdf a").on("click",function(e){ if($(this).parent().is(".cinza")) e.preventDefault();}

Isso bloqueia a ação do clique quando o botão tiver a classe 'cinza'

Comment: você sabe se da para fazer dentro desse exemplo que você fez enquanto o botão ser cinza ele bloqueie o href?

Comment: Da sim, eu editei ali minha resposta, já está bloqueando agora